# Simple MySQL JSON query takes very long time to resolve

Tags: mysql, json

A very simple query like `select * from vw_Json_Data where Ts < date_sub( now(), interval 1 day ) order by Ts desc limit 1` took > 5 minutes to resolve!

Monitoring the query using mysqladmin processlist showed that it was spending all that time 'Creating sort index'. How to reduce the query time something sensible (< 1 sec)?

The view `vw_Json_Data` is created as follows:

```
create table My_Json_Data (
  Id int auto_increment primary key,
  Tag_Id int, -- foreign key to the Tag table
  Ts datetime,
  Json_Data json
);

create table Tag (
  Tag_Id int auto_increment primary key,
  Val int
);

create or replace view vw_Json_Data as select * from Tag inner join My_Json_Data using( Tag_Id );
```

Currently, the Tag table contains about 2 million rows and the My_Json_Data contains 500,000 rows. Therefore, this should not be a problem for MySQL at all, albeit the Json_Data in My_Json_Data are quite complex and long JSON strings.

Comment: Note that queries against views cannot use indexes, rendering their utility questionable.

Comment: Incidentally, I cannot see that the presence or otherwise of JSON has any bearing on this problem.

Comment: "Note that queries against views cannot use indexes" - Not true according to 'explain'. We have lots of view like the above, but without any json data. Explain shows that it uses both primary keys and other indexes we've set up.

Comment: I did an experiment to confirm that it really was due to json. I did `create table xx_Json_Data like My_Json_Data`, then copied (inserted) all rows from My_Json_Data to xx_Json_Data but setting Json_Data to null. Running the same query on xx_Json_Data took < 1 sec. Then I updated all rows in xx_Json_Data with with Json_Data from My_Json_Data (i.e. xx_Json_Data now an exact copy of My_Json_Data) and ran the same query. Lo and behold, it took > 5 mins to return. Also, the submitted answer below implicates the presence of json as the cause.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation, what can be inferred is this. The extremely long 'Creating sort index' phase is due to the presence of JSON data. What it seems to be doing is creating sort indexes for the complex JSON for all rows that may match the query, instead of finding the row(s) that actually match first and then creating index for the JSON data from these found rows. Hence, the more rows in the table the much worse it will get.

The following, which is clearly more cumbersome but does the same thing as the original query, returns in 0.8 secs:

```
select *
from (
  -- grab the My_Json_Data.Id but DON'T grab the JSON data
  select A.*, Id
  from Tag A
  inner join My_Json_Data B using( Tag_Id )
  where Ts < date_sub( now(), interval 1 day )
  order by Ts desc
  limit 1
) A
inner join B My_Json_Data using( Tag_Id, Id );
```

If there's a better solution, please let me know:).

Answer (score 0):

I personally have a my own rules for using JSON in a relational DB (**2 is the solution**):

1.) Try to use JSON to store "complex" data not to query it. (Sometimes it's unavoidable, e.g. when you come into a live production DB`).

2.) If you need to query it in a relational database reference the queried data in a separate non-JSON column as well as in the JSON column. (From my experience and testing, this really optimizes speed as the DB scales). Trade off: extra data for a faster query (minimize extra data by only adding what needs to be queried).

3.) Remember to focus on the relationship aspect. If there is no relations between tables/data, is a relational DB the best choice. Other non-relational DBS with well documented and highly used features are out there. (E.G. Cassandra, Mongo DB).

Serverless relational DBs are awesome and have taken away some of the luster behind NoSQL (Serverless helped to solve scalability issues / storing complex data).